# Find max and min values in a column which is a result of summary operation

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor, azure-monitor-workbooks

I am trying to find out a way to calculate the maximum and minimum values of a column.

Using the query below, I first calculate the (requests per minute) RPM by using the summary operation and then want to pick max and min values for the RPM column.

I can technically use the take operation after ordering the column (asc or desc) to get either min or max value but it doesn't seem to be computationally efficient. Also, it only provides either max or min value and not both values at the same time.

The final output should be like following table:

```
RPM                   Timestamp
----                       
Max: value (e.g) 13 | 2022-03-02T14 
Min: value (e.g) 2  | 2022-03-06T11
```

```
let T = datatable(Timestamp:datetime, ResultType:string, ResultSignature:string, CorrelationId:string) [
"2022-03-02T14:35:05.6846874Z", "Throttled", "200", "a8de8a0b-2b95-4e16-a90f-d96c1f404850",
"2022-03-02T14:35:06.9535229Z", "Throttled", "200", "7e00ac15-6e82-42a5-8171-3145ae27728f",
"2022-03-02T14:34:21.1880149Z", "Non-Throttled", "200", "8fa9f7ee-6a91-4b8c-b170-9649befa698c",
"2022-03-02T14:34:36.9887590Z", "Non-Throttled", "200", "de7d82be-49b8-44dc-856c-16f76c7a4ae5",
"2022-03-02T14:34:39.3999879Z", "Non-Throttled", "200", "99b67d55-3ee4-4aee-9415-03919b2f23a4",
"2022-03-02T14:34:40.7854748Z", "Non-Throttled", "400", "dec5cd49-9d64-469a-83aa-db759c2e2fb1",
"2022-03-02T14:34:44.2007485Z", "Non-Throttled", "200", "5b412e71-6e48-49e2-9298-fd13d31619d1",
"2022-03-02T14:34:55.6858503Z", "Throttled", "200", "482592f9-722c-4f5d-8e48-967fa655d704",
"2022-03-02T14:25:17.0269766Z", "Throttled", "200", "1732c865-2474-4f76-b0cd-64af5981af7c",
"2022-03-02T14:25:18.9668944Z", "Throttled", "200", "234ec84c-3a0a-4329-a492-f8d590267ec6",
"2022-03-02T14:25:21.8262878Z", "Throttled", "200", "be8bd024-8f5c-4a01-9703-2945ef3bc8ba",
    ];
T 
| project Timestamp, ResultType, ResultSignature , CorrelationId
| summarize   RPM = count() by bin(Timestamp,1m)
| order by RPM desc
| take 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `arg_min()` and `arg_max()` aggregation functions, on top of your already-aggregated counts.

For example:

```
let T = datatable(Timestamp:datetime, ResultType:string, ResultSignature:string, CorrelationId:string) [
"2022-03-02T14:35:05.6846874Z", "Throttled", "200", "a8de8a0b-2b95-4e16-a90f-d96c1f404850",
"2022-03-02T14:35:06.9535229Z", "Throttled", "200", "7e00ac15-6e82-42a5-8171-3145ae27728f",
"2022-03-02T14:34:21.1880149Z", "Non-Throttled", "200", "8fa9f7ee-6a91-4b8c-b170-9649befa698c",
"2022-03-02T14:34:36.9887590Z", "Non-Throttled", "200", "de7d82be-49b8-44dc-856c-16f76c7a4ae5",
"2022-03-02T14:34:39.3999879Z", "Non-Throttled", "200", "99b67d55-3ee4-4aee-9415-03919b2f23a4",
"2022-03-02T14:34:40.7854748Z", "Non-Throttled", "400", "dec5cd49-9d64-469a-83aa-db759c2e2fb1",
"2022-03-02T14:34:44.2007485Z", "Non-Throttled", "200", "5b412e71-6e48-49e2-9298-fd13d31619d1",
"2022-03-02T14:34:55.6858503Z", "Throttled", "200", "482592f9-722c-4f5d-8e48-967fa655d704",
"2022-03-02T14:25:17.0269766Z", "Throttled", "200", "1732c865-2474-4f76-b0cd-64af5981af7c",
"2022-03-02T14:25:18.9668944Z", "Throttled", "200", "234ec84c-3a0a-4329-a492-f8d590267ec6",
"2022-03-02T14:25:21.8262878Z", "Throttled", "200", "be8bd024-8f5c-4a01-9703-2945ef3bc8ba",
]
;
let M = materialize(
    T
    | summarize RPM = count() by bin(Timestamp, 1m)
    | summarize (minRpm, minT) = arg_min(RPM, Timestamp),
                (maxRpm, maxT) = arg_max(RPM, Timestamp)
);
union 
(M | project RPM = minRpm, Timestamp = minT, Label = "Min"),
(M | project RPM = maxRpm, Timestamp = maxT, Label = "Max")
```

Comment: I would consider doing the materialization only after an additional summarize (one for both arg_min & arg_max)

Comment: Thanks, Yoni. I notice the output generated is on the singe row "2 | 3/2/2022, 9:36:00 AM
13 |3/2/2022, 9:26:00 AM". Would it be possible to have max and min on separate rows?

Comment: answer modified per your request